# Spotify API Python

Tags: python, spotify

I am following a tutorial from CodingEntrepreneurs and i have come across a road bump where it returns a 400 error when i run it.

Here is my code

```
import base64, requests
import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlencode

client_id = "my id"
client_secret = "my secret"


class SpotifyAPI(object):
    access_token = None
    access_token_expires = datetime.datetime.now()
    access_token_did_expire = True
    client_id = None
    client_secret = None
    token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"



    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    def getClientCreds(self):
        '''Returns b64 encoded string'''
        client_id = self.client_id
        client_secret = self.client_secret

        if client_id == None or client_secret == None:
            raise Exception('Must set a client id and secret')

        client_creds  = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"
        client_creds_b64 = base64.b64encode(client_creds.encode())
        return client_creds_b64.decode()

    def getTokenHeader(self):
        client_creds_b64 = self.getClientCreds()
        return {
            'Authorization':f"Basic {client_creds_b64}"
        }

    def getTokenData(self):
        return {
            "grant_type":"client_credentials"
        }

    def perform_auth(self):
        token_url = self.token_url
        token_data = self.getTokenData()
        token_header = self.getTokenHeader()

        r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data, headers=token_header)

        if r.status_code  not in range(200,299):
            return False

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        token_response_data = r.json()
        access_token = token_response_data['access_token']
        expires_in = token_response_data['expires_in']
        expires = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=expires_in)
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.access_token_expires = expires
        self.access_token_did_expire = expires < now


        return True




spotify = SpotifyAPI(client_id, client_secret)
print(spotify.perform_auth())
token = spotify.access_token

header = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer{token}", 
}
endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
data = urlencode({"q": "Time", "type": "track"})

lookupURL = f"{endpoint}?{data}"

r = requests.get(lookupURL, headers=header)
print(r.json())
```

When i run this it returns this 
"
True

{'error': {'status': 400, 'message': 'Only valid bearer authentication supported'}}
"
Please could someone help and explain the solution.

Thanks,
Sam :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be a problem here, as you are leaving no space between the `Bearer` keyword and the token:

```py
# previous
header = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer{token}", 
}

# correct
header = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}", 
}
```

Comment: i tried your answert but now the `perform_auth()` returns False

Comment: Leaving the space between the `Bearer` keyword and the token does not resolve it?

Comment: @user8408080  when it worked 200, when it didnt 400